# Concating text in ng-model

Tags: angularjs

In my view :

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="imageUrl = fullImageUrl(job.imageUrl);" />
```

My application controller :

```
    $scope.fullImageUrl=function(imageUrl){

    return '/img/'+imageUrl;
}
```

Problem is that , when i browse it shows -

```
/img/undefined
```

I don't want this. I want blank , before executing my function.

Comment: thanks.. It is working !!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not the best idea to use an assignment in `ng-model`. It expects an expression, not an assignment. This is how it should look:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="fullImageUrl(job.imageUrl)" />
```

Then if you want it not to show `undefined` you can just check it in your function and assign an empty string `""` to it.
Try something like this:

```
$scope.fullImageUrl=function(imageUrl){
    if (!imageUrl) imageUrl = "";
    return '/img/'+imageUrl;
}
```

Comment: Ok.. But it works perfectly.. <input type="text"  ng-model="imageUrl = fullImageUrl(job.imageUrl);" /> .. You should try

Comment: It might work, but it's probably not a great idea to assign variables inside your template. If your specific needs require you to do it that way, then by no means go for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.fullImageUrl=function(imageUrl){
    if (!imageUrl) {            
        return "";
        }

    return '/img/'+imageUrl;
}
```

Here i am passing imageUrl as parameter and at first it is undefined. Thats why when !imageUrl , it will return empty string and show it on view . As soon as it gets the value , it will not enter into "if- condition" and return the given code.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.